# Discover titles/paragraphs in word docs

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to discover paragraphs/titles in word documents. 

I use Apache POI to do this. 

An example that I use is:

```
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filesname));
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
            ArrayList titles = new ArrayList();

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < we.getText().length() - 1; i++) {
                    int startIndex = i;
                    int endIndex = i + 1;
                    Range range = new Range(startIndex, endIndex, doc);
                    CharacterRun cr = range.getCharacterRun(0);

                    if (cr.isBold() || cr.isItalic() || cr.getUnderlineCode() != 0) {
                        while (cr.isBold() || cr.isItalic() || cr.getUnderlineCode() != 0) {
                            i++;
                            endIndex += 1;
                            range = new Range(endIndex, endIndex + 1, doc);
                            cr = range.getCharacterRun(0);
                        }
                        range = new Range(startIndex, endIndex - 1, doc);
                        titles.add(range.text());
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException iobe) {
                //sometimes this happens have to find out why.
            }`enter code here`
```

This works for all bold, italic or underlined text. 

 But what I want is to discover the font that is used most often. And then to discover variations compared to that font style.

Anyone an Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Well, some thoughts would be to try some of the following:

- `cr.getFontSize()` could be used at the beginning of a paragraph to see if the range changes font size. That in conjunction with bold, italic or underlined would be a good identifier.
- `cr.getFontName()` could also be used to determine when and where the font changes in a given range.
- `cr.getColor()` would be another possibility to help identify if the user is using different colors for a font.

I guess I would iterate over the range and create multiple `CharacterRun` items each time the text characteristics change. Then evaluate each item based on position in the paragraph as well as all of the afore-mentioned characteristics (size, color, name, bold, italics, etc.). Perhaps create some sort of weighting scale based on the most common values.

It might also be of value to create a `Title` object and store the values for each set of characteristics to help optimize searches in later character runs in the same document.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the *buildParagraphTagAndStyle* method in Tika's WordExtractor:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordExtractor.java

For HWPF (.doc), to call it you'd do:

```
      StyleDescription style = 
         document.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(p.getStyleIndex());
      TagAndStyle tas = buildParagraphTagAndStyle(
            style.getName(), (parentTableLevel>0)
      );
```

For XWPF (.docx) you'd do:

```
      XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(paragraph.getStyleID());

      TagAndStyle tas = WordExtractor.buildParagraphTagAndStyle(
            style.getName(), paragraph.getPartType() == BodyType.TABLECELL
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier if you process the data by converting it into paragraphs.

```
 WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
 String[] para = we.getParagraphText();
```

Then work paragraph wise. If your code already couldn't figure out the titles, then you can check for bold and underlines in each paragraph.

The paragraphs function as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<para.length;i++)
{
System.out.println("Length of paragraph "+(i+1)+": "+ para[i].length());
    System.out.println(para[i].toString());
}
```

A working example can be found here: 
http://sanjaal.com/java/120/java-file/how-to-read-doc-file-using-java-and-apache-poi/#comments